# Exposing Just a Single Property Value from the Code

Tags: wpf

I want to bind a single property from my datacontext and diplay on UI.

How can I display the property Address in a texblock?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string fullname;
    public string FullName
    {
        get 
        {
            return fullname;
        }
        set
        {
            fullname = value;
            OnPropertChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the Property to a textblock first in

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Person _myWindowModel = new Person()
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _myWindowModel;
    }
}
```

and after that in your Window in WPF go to the TextBlock and add:

```
Text="{Binding FullName}"
```

Comment: I think he want to do the binding in code behind and not in xaml

Comment: @Guerudo you are right, i want to do the bind in the code behind

Comment: it's working, i'm sorry...i try it first in a wrong way...thanks a lot